# get value in array and add text

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i need help abut this syntax  the error in $time[0][$weekday'_01From']

```
<?php
$dayOfWeek = array("Sat", "Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri");
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
$weekday = $dayOfWeek[$i];

echo "<tr>";echo "<td>$weekday</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='true'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='time' name='".$weekday."_01From"."' value='". $time[0][$weekday'_01From']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='time' name='".$weekday."_01To"."' value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input type='time' name='".$weekday."_02From"."' value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input type='time' name='".$weekday."_02To"."' value=''></td>";
echo "<tr>";?>
```

Comment: If I'm right, change `$time[0][$weekday'_01From']` to `$time[0][$weekday.'_01From']`. It will fix your problem

Comment: What is this array time?

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate:  `$time[0][$weekday . '_01From']`

You're also missing a closing brace on your `for` loop

Comment: You should [add a link to the manual for string operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) IMO